# Issue changing class of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change class of `#sliderImg` element using this code below, it always returns default value, 'fade-out', is this the proper way to change class names?

```
$('#sliderImg' + i).className='fade-in';        
alert($('#sliderImg' + i).attr('class'));
```

Based on the code from the site:

http://wbruno.com.br/css/fadein-e-fadeout-com-css-3/

Comment: This should work: $('#sliderImg' + i).addClass('fade-in')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using jQuery with `$`. Try using `addClass`/`removeClass`/`toggleClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
$('#sliderImg' + i).addClass( "fade-in" );
```

You get more info on jQuery page: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/